# Css applying linear-gradient to body of document

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I am trying to make this gradient appear on entire body of document, but instead it just shows only on the top. Is there anyway to fill it up entire body? I am using firefox if that makes difference.

```
body {
        height: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, blue 80%, green 0);
    }
```

Comment: Add this: `html { height:100% }`

Comment: You would be better off using an image instead of that gradient, its just 2 lines, no gradient. You are also missing a few fallbacks etc.. I recommend:http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @Mark Why use an image instead? That's an additional http request.

Comment: @TonyBarnes, yes normally, but for something that simple, a small image is better than having to css for multiple browsers and fallbacks

Comment: Sometimes it's tempting to use webkit's drawing features, like -webkit-gradient, when it's not actually necessary - maintaining images and dealing with Photoshop and drawing tools can be a hassle. However, using CSS for those tasks moves that hassle from the designer's computer to the target's CPU. Gradients, shadows, and other decorations in CSS should be used only when necessary (e.g. when the shape is dynamic based on the content) - otherwise, static images are always faster. On very low-end platforms, it's even advised to use static images for some of the text if possible.

Comment: Przemoa, was my answer below any use to you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a 100% height for the html and body tags:

```
html,
body {
  height:100%;
}


body {
  background:#BAF7C8;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, #BAF7C8),
    color-stop(1, #5C93DB)
  );
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #BAF7C8 0%, #5C93DB 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BAF7C8 0%, #5C93DB 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BAF7C8 0%, #5C93DB 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BAF7C8 0%, #5C93DB 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #BAF7C8 0%, #5C93DB 100%);
}
```

(gradient generated from [css3factory](http://www.css3factory.com/linear-gradients/)).

Notice there is a regular background colour fallback as well.

You could generate the gradients automatically with [autoprefixer](https://css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33gpa1xc/1/show)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper code to make sure you get your linear gradient.

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {  
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg ,white, orange);
}
```

This method works in almost all modern browsers. Hope this helped.